# (HCS12 Microcontroller: Assembly Language) Which branch is appropriate for this loop?

Tags: loops, assembly, branch

What I'm really stuck on is how I'm supposed to make this loop properly I tried doing every combination for each branch but it either never stops or it stops at the wrong number of loops (supposed to stop after amount of values in RPN_START). I even tried what I did in a previous lab which also failed to work so I'm completely lost as to how I'm supposed to get this program to loop. I understand that the RPN_OUT is the end pointer of the array so I tried putting RPN_START with CPY to compare the values but doing that made it stop after one loop. So I don't know at all which branch I'm supposed to use. Any help/tips/advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

```
 ORG     DATA
;RPN_IN    FCB     $06,$03,$2F,$04,$2A,$02,$2B  ; 63/4*2+=10
;RPN_IN    FCB     $05,$01,$02,$2B,$04,$2A,$2B,$03,$2D  ; 512+4*+3-
;RPN_IN    FCB     $02,$03,$2A,$05,$2A,$02,$2F,$01, $2B ; ( ( (2 * 3) * 5) / 2) + 1
RPN_IN    FCB     $11,$10,$2F,$15,$2A   ; ( (11 / 10) ) * 15
RPN_OUT   RMB     1

RPN_START FDB     RPN_IN                ; Pointer to start of RPN array
RPN_END   FDB     RPN_OUT               ; Pointer to end of RPN array          
ANSWER    RMB     1
TEMP      FCB     $00        
      ORG     PROG

Entry:                          ; KEEP THIS LABEL!!

      LDS      #PROG
      LDX      #RPN_IN     

LOOP:
TFR X,A
 LDAA X
...
PSHA
RET:
INX
CPX  #RPN_OUT 
BNE   LOOP      
PULA
STAA ANSWER
```

Comment: Usually, to loop on an array of size N, the end of the loop is `i = i+1`, `loop if i != N`. This means that you should compare with `RPN_OUT`. Also, `RPN_END` is a pointer, so you will never want `RPN_END-1` here.

Comment: I tried that but RPN_END points to RPN_OUT so it gives the same results as RPN_END does. I tried #RPN_OUT-1 and that looped correctly but gave a couple of warning and didn't store the correct answer. I tested the in between code before and it worked how it was supposed to. So I'm completely lost now ;-;

Comment: Please I really really need help; my level of knowledge in assembly is 10x worse than my knowledge of higher level languages I really don't understand what's the difference between each branch. And I can't find any tutorials or tips online on how to use branches for loops its extremely frustrating.

Comment: If you can have the generated assembly that would be convenient for you to understand what you are doing. Did you try to just remove all the `-1` (leaving the rest as you posted) ? Update your question after.

Comment: Yeah I did that. I tried RPN_OUT-1, RPN_OUT with a few branch combinations like BLE, BLT, and BNE

Comment: Not like that. Just remove all the `-1`. `RPN_END FDB RPN_OUT` and `CMPB  RPN_END`. `CMPB  #RPN_OUT` should also work.

Comment: Also, you don't load `X` correctly. You need to get the pointer to the array. Either `RPN_START` or `#RPN_IN`.

Comment: I changed it but whenever I do the loop it loops past the array length and B has values A,B,C,D,E,F then 10 and then it stops

Comment: Another point I just noticed : You use `B` as your "current index/pointer", but you don't actually initialize it. You need the correct `LDAB` or `TFR` for that.

Comment: You should probably use `X` as your "current pointer". This will make it easier to use. You need to use `INX` and `CPX` for that.

Comment: I need to load the values from X also though and what does TFR do?

Comment: `TFR` just move one register to another. Using `X` as your current pointer makes it easy to access your array of values and check for the end of loop at the same time. You initialize `X` with `#RPN_IN` (better than `RPN_START`), you load your values with `LDA* X`, and you loop with `INX; CPX; BNE`. You can probably remove `RPN_START` and `RPN_END` entirely (or define them as aliases, if the assembler permits it).

Comment: It loops now but it transfers the index value from X to A?

Comment: Yes, `TFR X, A` will do X => A. You don't need `TFR` for the loop part if you do things this way. You don't need to load ANSWER at the beginning either ; its value is undefined. You could load the pointer to ANSWER with `#ANSWER` (to Y, for example), but only if your algorithm needs it. If you compute your result in A, `STAA ANSWER` at the end will do.

Comment: It loops correctly now. I just figure out why its not outputting the correct answer now. Thank you so much! :D

Comment: Don't hesitate to consult your [reference manual](http://www.nxp.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/ref_manual/CPU12RM.pdf). `LDAA B, X` means `A = X[B];`, and it definitely looks wrong here. To load the current value from your array in A, you just need `LDAA X`.

Comment: I changed it to that and I do check it but they don't show examples so its kind of confusing. Does the pulx function remove 2 values from the stack?

Comment: `PULX` removes 1 value of 2 bytes. You could say it removes 2 values of 1 byte, but semantically the former is more correct. Anyway, 2 bytes are removed from the stack and put in X.